# When I am trying to boot I am getting this error

Tags: boot

I am getting this error when I am trying to boot.
It says recovering journal then some ACPI errors.

It's a normal single booted Ubuntu system 22.04 it was running fine but when I booted today it's showing this error.

I have provided the error message picture link [picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TniUR.jpg)

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; no clues if you're trying to boot a *live* system (ie. the system isn't yet installed), it was an installed system (*where details of what was changed prior session before this issue would be useful*) etc.   Recovering journal maybe attributed to user failing to safely shutdown system in prior session (eg. using power button instead of safe shutdown SysRq command)

Comment: I had provided the error message picture earlier but it was not showing now it's showing

Comment: Thanks for the additional details (*and adding them to your question*) but you didn't specify if you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop.  Did you make any changes during the last session when it booted normally?

Comment: This is my desktop

Comment: Can you try to boot up an older kernel from grub menu?

Comment: I have tried that it's showing the same problem